# How I can Reach all partitions in the hard drive in c#

Tags: c#

How can I reach all partitions in the hard drive in c# just without writing the directory path. Because some people part the harddisk to 3, 4 maybe five and I want my program completely searcher.

like this

```
List<string> dirs = FileHelper.GetFilesRecursive("c:\\..........");
```

I don't want just C I want D ,E ,F.......etc

Comment: Your drive C is not a physical drive, it is a partition (maybe the only one or one out of several) on a physical drive.

Answer (score 5):

you can use [Environment.GetLogicalDrives()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getlogicaldrives.aspx) to get a list of all the drives (both physical and logical partitions).

Answer (score 4):

You could use:

```
// Store the list of drives into an array of string
string[] DriveList = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();
// Loop through the array
for (int i = 0; i < DriveList.Length; i++)
{
    // Show each drive
    MessageBox.Show(DriveList[i]);
}
```